# Photo viewer with EXIF rotation and comment editor

Tags: linux, open-source, images, image-viewer, exif

We have about one gigabyte sized collection of family photos. For each photo we would like to specify rotation angle (90 DEGREES or -90 DEGREES) and a one-line comment.

There are individual image viewers like **Viewnior** and **Eye of Gnome**, but I think they do not have a field for comments. There is **KPhotoViewer**, **KODI** (xmbc), but I haven't seen a field for comments there, either. For either of them I do not know how they implement rotation, via metadata or by modifying the bytes within the image area.

I am looking for a free software (libre, not necessarily gratis) solution that works on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [photo/image database with EXIF, tags and comments/description](https://superuser.com/questions/40919/photo-image-database-with-exif-tags-and-comments-description)

Answer (score 0):

What about [geeqie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geeqie) ([website](http://www.geeqie.org/)) and its plugins?

*Viewing* all Exif Data is certainly possible `CTRL+E` - opening the EXIF Window. You should open sthis sidebar to see the effect of the next action:

**Changing orientation:**
You can "rotate" (change the orientation in the EXIF) with the `[` and `]` keys. In a second step do not forget to write the "annotated-as-rotated" image to disk with `Edit/Orientation/Apply the orientation to image content`.

Editing is not possible with the Exif *Window,* so use this workaround just described.

**Adding a comment:**
*Editing* some non-Exif Metadata Data is possible with `CTRL-K`. This opens the *Info Sidebar*  which has a "Comment" field at the bottom of the page, but that is not an EXIF tag, apparently.

What is the tag that you want to edit? `Exif.Image.Description`?

Comment: Thank you knb for sharing this information. To answer your questions, 1) I don't want to rotate the bitmap because that loses image quality, instead specify rotation in EXIF metadata or a file located in the same directory as the image? 2) Yes I would like to modify the image description.

Comment: There is a plugin for geeqie that does lossless JPG rotation. -- Try the CTRL-S and `Edit/Orientation...` operations yourself to what see what exactly they do to an image. -- There are other tags which also candidates for new content e.g. `Exif.Image.Title`

Comment: Thank you for this explanation knb. I don't see image description in the metadata dialog.